# iOS how to insert a local file URL into NSURLConnection response data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to modify a behavior of a webpage within my iOS app and make the in-page media player play a file from the local caches folder instead of fetching it from a web server.

Below is my code that replaces the http:// video path with a local file path. The code does not work, giving me "Resource Temporary not available. Please try again" error message popup. **Is it possible to have a web-based media player play file from a local disk using file URL?** 
I tried substituting these for the instanceURL, but they don't seem to work.

```
[fileURL path]
[fileURL absolutePath]
```

I'm intercepting the request for the file and am parsing it to find out that the page is asking for a video file:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    // An NSURLConnection delegate callback.  We pass this on to the client.
{


    NSDictionary* decisionDictionary = [[RequestListener sharedInstance] shouldContinue:connection processRequestData:data];

    BOOL shouldContinue = [decisionDictionary[@"shouldContinue"] boolValue];

    if(shouldContinue == NO)
    {
        return;
    }else
    {
        NSData* d = data;
        //substitute fake data
        if(decisionDictionary[@"data"])
        {
            d = decisionDictionary[@"data"];
        }

        [[self client] URLProtocol:self didLoadData:d];

    }


}
```

Within my shouldContinue method, I check if the video is present locally and modify the response data to create a path to a local video.

```
    NSString* path = [VideoDownloader localVideoPathForVideoID:videoID];
     NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

DLog(@"url:%@",[fileURL absoluteString]);
     NSString* replacement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"instanceUrl\":\"%@\"",[[fileURL absoluteURL] absoluteString]];
      DLog(@"replacement:%@",replacement);
      NSString* forgedResponse = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@","];
      NSData* forgedData = [forgedResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      return @{@"shouldContinue":@(YES),@"data":forgedData};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can intercept http requests before they are sent to a host to decide what to do about it: Continue to server, redirect to local cache.

There's a decent [tutorial by our beloved Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial).

Apple has a [programming guide as well](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).